# How to delete extra kernel images?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I have Ubuntu installed on a partition with very minimal space. Every so often, the update manager informs me that there are some updates to install.

One of those updates is the kernel itself. The new kernel is installed alongside the old and a new item appears on the Grub boot menu.

My question is... how do you get rid of the old kernel images? They're just taking up space.

Comment: Careful. Don't ever get rid of at least the second most recent kernel until you know for sure that your system boots into it and is stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! I just figured it out.

All you have to do is use synaptic to remove them.